# how to output integers and doubles to binary file

Tags: c++, integer, double, binaryfiles

I'm working on an assignment and I'm getting stuck on one part of it, the output of integers and doubles to a binary file.

I know I need to use the write() function along with using the binary flag for the output stream, however write() requires a character array to output.  When I'm outputting a regular string I can just typecast it using (char *) or use the .c_str() function, however I'm having trouble with the doubles and integers.

How would I go about outputting integers and doubles to binary?

Comment: Do you need them human-readable?

Comment: I just need to output integers and doubles to a binary file.  The binary file's contents do not need to be human-readable though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dereference your variable, and then cast the pointer to a `char*`, then use `sizeof()` to determine how many bytes to write. For instance:

```
int var;
char* varAsCharP = (char*)&var;
size_t bytesToWrite = sizeof(int);
```

Also, if you need the file to be portable, you might want to for instance convert the variable to network byte order first, using the various hton functions (when saving), and ntoh functions (when reading back) - although that only goes for integers.

Comment: Don't forget to pass the size of the type when writing though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stdlib methods described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0heszx3w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

or you can use `boost::lexical_cast`

or you can use `stringstream`

take your pick

if you want just the byte representation then you could do a memcpy like so:

```
int myVar = 10;
char * dest = new char[sizeof(myVar)];
memcpy(&dest, &myVar, sizeof(myVar));
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to write the byte representation of the values, not a string representation.

Comment: in that case can just do a simple memcpy, `char * dest = new char[sizeof(src)]; memcpy(&dest, src, sizeof(src));`

Comment: Typo: `&src` in `memcpy`. Yes, can do that.